# Why is this HTML element starting indented, and how can I get it to start at the left page edge?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML element which insists on starting indented, running from below the right-hand end of the element above it, and I would like it to start from the left page edge. How can I achieve this?

For a reason I don't understand, the problem disappears when the element is made longer, for example if "Hello" in the code below is replaced with the word "Hello" repeated 14 times.

I have pared the code down to the bare minimum that has the problem.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#row1 {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#row1-col1 {
  max-width: 570px;
}

.row1-header {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button-left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div id="row1-col1">
    <span class="button-left"><a href="#1">Previous</a></span>
    <span class="button-right"><a href="#2">Next</a></span>
    <br>
    <div class="row1-header">
      Hello
    </div>
    <!--close row1-header-->
  </div>
  <!--close row1-col1-->
</div>
<!--close row1-->
```

**Edit**

@Jeff's suggestion of removing `float: left` from `button-left` solves the problem as stated above, so I have given him the tick, but the unpared code has a right-hand button on the same line as the left-hand one, and removing `float-left` from the left-hand one puts them out of sync. So the problem has morphed into how can I change the following code to stop the word "hello" from indenting, leaving everything else about the result as it is.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#row1 {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#row1-col1 {
  max-width: 570px;
}

.row1-header {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button-left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button-right {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div id="row1-col1">
    <span class="button-left"><a href="#1">Previous</a></span>
    <span class="button-right"><a href="#2">Next</a></span>
    <br>
    <div class="row1-header">
      Hello
    </div>
    <!--close row1-header-->
  </div>
  <!--close row1-col1-->
</div>
<!--close row1-->
```

Comment: Use your browsers developer tools. Inspect the space/area. It's probably a margin or padding set on `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
.button-left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Remove the `float: left;`

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem in the code I posted here, but in the actual code I've got a right-hand button that floats right on the same line as the left-hand button, and removing the float from the left button, while solving the "hello" problem, puts the two buttons out of sync.

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer worked for you, please marked it. And for the new problem that'd be need you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

`clear: left` on `.row1-header` will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get that to work even on the pared down code above.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need `inline-block` for `row1-header` remove that and clear the floats. Currently, it is not its own block element and is attempting to be styled with the previous lines as an inline element.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#row1 {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#row1-col1 {
  max-width: 570px;
}

.row1-header {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  clear:both;
}

.button-left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button-right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div id="row1-col1">
    <span class="button-left"><a href="#1">Previous</a></span>
    <span class="button-right"><a href="#2">Next</a></span>
    <br>
    <div class="row1-header">
      Hello
    </div>
    <!--close row1-header-->
  </div>
  <!--close row1-col1-->
</div>
<!--close row1-->
```

Comment: This does it. Thanks! In fact `clear:both;` on its own works.